# Set request attribute and then redirect to another app in a Spring Controller

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-mvc, spring-security

How can I set a request attribute and then redirect that to another app in a Spring Controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this answer, I think this is what are you looking for

[How to pass model attributes from one Spring MVC controller to another controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429649/how-to-pass-model-attributes-from-one-spring-mvc-controller-to-another-controller/7430013#7430013)