# How to send parameter from controller in other controller in springMVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In post method I did generate an object and try to send him into another Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/main")
    public ModelAndView makesQuery(
            @RequestParam String query
    ){
//   create new explorer if
        Explorer explorer = explorerService.createByQuery(query);

//   determine status of explorer
        StatusEnum q = StatusEnum.getEnum(explorer.getStatus().getStatusName());

        String http = q == StatusEnum.FINISHED ?
                "redirect:/show" : "redirect:/parsing";

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(http);
        modelAndView.addObject("explorer", explorer);

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

---

in next method I try to get object Explorer:

```
@GetMapping("/parsing")
public ModelAndView makesQuery(
        @ModelAttribute Explorer explorer
) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("search");
    modelAndView.addObject("explorer", explorer);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

But have next error:

> Error resolving template "parsing", template might not exist or might
>   not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

---

When i change annotation for Explorer from @ModelAttribute to @RequestParam:

```
@GetMapping("/parsing")
public ModelAndView makesQuery(
        @RequestParam Explorer explorer
) {......
```

I did have error in browser:

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Aug 15 14:15:52 EEST 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Bad
>   Request, status=400). Required Explorer parameter 'explorer' is not
>   present

PS
search.html file not have any logic in body - only string "test".

Comment: search for `RedirectAttributes`

Comment: see here e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19587418/3959856

Comment: Jack Flamp, thanks! That did help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the explore object in session.

HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute( "explorer", explorer)

And to get

@GetMapping("/parsing")
public ModelAndView makesQuery(HttpServletRequest request..)
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
Explore explore = session.getAttribute("exolorer")

Comment: where I can take method 'request' in string HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); session.setAttribute( "explorer", explorer)

?

Comment: public ModelAndView makesQuery(
            @RequestParam String query, HttpServletRequest request
    )