# Spring MVC - Transferring the same object from one page to other

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-form

In my Spring MVC application, I have 2 pages.
I have an object with 10 variables in it.
In the first page, I am setting 9 variables of the above object(first page has 9 fields).
I set this object in session as well as model attribute in the controller.
I also need to pass this same object to the next page.
In the second page, I need to set the 10th variable in the same object(second page has only one field 10th field).
(why I need a second page for setting the 10th variable is - In the second page, I populate a dropdown based on the entries in the first page)

When I submit the form in the second page - I need to submit the same object with 10 variables.
(I couldn't paste the code because of my company policy)
Can anyone please help me in fixing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass model attributes from one Spring MVC controller to another controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429649/how-to-pass-model-attributes-from-one-spring-mvc-controller-to-another-controlle)

Comment: I already tried the above link. but no luck. this is a different scenario. please read the content clearly.

Comment: if possible post the code of pages and the controller methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that both methods are in the same controller. You need to do something like this:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("myObject")
public class SessionAttributesController {

    // Save session attribute in model. 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/page1.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page1( @ModelAttribute MyClass myObject, ModelMap model ) {
        model.addtAttribute("myObject", myObject);
        return "page1.html";
    }

    // Now you model is having myObject, so it has to be used in jsp. You can add ModelMap parameter to this method and check what contains model in debug mode.   
    @RequestMapping(value = "/page2.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page(ModelMap model) {
          model.get("myObject").setAttr10(value);   
          return "page2.html";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in this way:

```
@Controller
public class PageController {
    @RequestMapping("/page1")
    public String showPage1(Model model) {
        Obj obj = new Obj();
        model.addAttribute("obj", obj);
        return "test/page1";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/page2")
    public String showPage2(@ModelAttribute Obj obj, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("obj", obj);
        return "test/page2";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/page3")
    public String showPage3(@ModelAttribute Obj obj, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("obj", obj);
        return "test/page3";
    }
}
```

Page 1 (relevant part only):

```
<sf:form modelAttribute="obj" action="page2">
<sf:input path="field1"/><br/>
<sf:input path="field2"/><br/>
<sf:input path="field3"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="To page 2">
</sf:form>
```

Page 2:

```
<sf:form modelAttribute="obj" action="page3">
<sf:hidden path="field1"/>
<sf:hidden path="field2"/>
<sf:hidden path="field3"/>
<sf:input path="field4"/><br/>
<sf:input path="field5"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="To page 3">
</sf:form>
```

Page 3 serves only to display all object fields which were entered on previous 2 pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you think you will have of these wizard type screens, you should consider using [spring-webflow](http://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/). Spring-Webflow's DSL will help you manage more complex scenarios if they arise.

You can get a basic introduction about Spring-Webflow from [here](http://www.ervacon.com/products/swf/intro/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have considered all other options( I mean model attribute etc) , 
I would suggest using Spring-Web-Flow to do this (if the two pages you are talking about were related), this way you can ensure that data will be transferred from one page to another.

Ref:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/1.0.3/reference/practical.html

Hope this works.

Regards
Ashok Gudise