# Value is not printed on JSP page

Tags: spring-mvc

```
model.addAttribute("error",ErrorMessages.USERLOGINERROR);
```

is not working while using redirect

```
return "redirect:/userlogin";
```

I have google it but not found approciate answer

```
if(name.equals("false")){
System.out.println(ErrorMessages.USERLOGINERROR);
model.addAttribute("error",ErrorMessages.USERLOGINERROR);
return "redirect:/getuserloginpage";
}
```

JSP:

```
<form:form action="userlogin" method="post" commandname="login">
<div align="center" style="color: red">${error}</div>
<div align="center" style="color: red">${thanks}</div>
...
```

expected result should be :

> Please check your email or password. actual results : printed nothing.
>   (no error or exception found)

Comment: You might need to put the complete code,the jsp snippet where you are printing and the controller as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass model attributes from one Spring MVC controller to another controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429649/how-to-pass-model-attributes-from-one-spring-mvc-controller-to-another-controlle)

Comment: Actually, my query is different. I have to pass value from controller to jsp in case of redirection, not from controller to controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one thing, you are using

```
return "redirect:/userlogin";
```

it means you have

```
@RequestMapping(value="/userlogin", method=GET)
public String yourMethod(Model model)
{
 your code.....
 return some_page_name;// from tiles.xml or directly as per you configuration
}

now use the same return

if(name.equals("false")){
System.out.println(ErrorMessages.USERLOGINERROR);
model.addAttribute("error",ErrorMessages.USERLOGINERROR);
//return "redirect:/getuserloginpage";
return some_page_name;  // simple and easy but take care of functionality
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal model attributes will not work with redirect.

Use redirect attributes instead like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someURL", method=GET)
public String yourMethod(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
{
   ...
   redirectAttributes.addAttribute("rd", "rdValue");
   redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("fa", faValue);
   return "redirect:/someOtherURL";
}
```